# How to create dynamic charts in angular with canvas?

Tags: html, angular, canvas

I have situtation in which I am getting list of objects from the backend and this list would vary upon the request sometime there could be 6 objects in the list and sometime less. So I want to achieve dynamic creation of the piecharts.

So what I have tried is to iterate the object list like the following

TS And HTML

```
makeChart() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.benchmarkData.length; i++) {
      this.integrationActions = new Chart("PieChart" + i, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
          labels: this.benchmarkData[i].labels,
          datasets: [{
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            data: this.benchmarkData[i].values,
            backgroundColor: ['#299aff', '#ff4961', '#ffe802', '#9080e8', '#28dac6'],
            borderWidth: 0,
          }],

        },
        options: {
          aspectRatio: 3,
          responsive: true,
          legend: {
            position: 'left',
            display: true,
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 mt-3" *ngFor="let benchmarkDataIndex of benchmarkData; let i = index">
    <p>{{'PieChart'+ i}}</p>
    <div class="graph-section">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)"
         (click)="routBenchMark(benchmarkDataIndex.name,benchmarkDataIndex.policyId)">
        <h2>{{benchmarkDataIndex.name}}</h2></a>
      <div class="chart-container" [class.hidden]="showNoRecord === true">
        <canvas id="PieChart'+ i}}"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So when I did this I got the error
`benchmarkchart.component.ts:61 Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item`

What could be the possible issue with this approch and if any how can I handle this situtation ?